# SharedApplication.openUrl hides own app

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

When using SharedApplication.openUrl to open e.g. mail program on iOS, the app gets hidden at the same time the mail program opens.

Is there any way to keep the app in the background? So when the user exists the mail program, it will return to the app?

At least for me, when existing the mail program, my own app stays hidden. If I click the app icon in iOS, it does open immediately where left, but I still find it a little annoying :(

Comment: @SirRufo Okay. Thanks for info. Feel to make it an answer, and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is as designed by iOS.

BTW "exiting the mail app" is done by pressing the homebutton, and everyone expects to return to homescreen.